# Stop Server.TransferRequest from using the query string of the current request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

The documentation for [`Server.TransferRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344901.aspx) contains the following remark:

> If the *path* parameter specifies a query string, it will be used as the new query string. If no query string is included, the query string of the request will be re-used.

How can I transfer a request with a query string to a path without a query string?

Comment: Take a step back and explain your underlying business problem.

Comment: Server.TransferRequest is an artifact of ASP.NET that is totally unnecessary if you are using MVC. All you need to do in MVC is to route the request to exactly where it needs to go. But as mjwillis pointed out, it would help if you explain what business problem you are trying to solve. If you are trying to change the URL of the browser, then you just need to redirect.

Comment: @mjwills @NightOwl888 This is really unrelated to the question, but here's my business problem. When an error occurs, I need to render the previous (requesting) page, with an added alert box on top. My Web.config is configured to execute the path `/error` on error. My error handler checks the referrer and transfers the request when possible.

Comment: IIS's error handling appends the query string with unescaped data ([see this](https://serverfault.com/questions/586875/iis-httperrors-executeurl-appends-weird-query-string-like-500http-mysite-com)). I want to remove this invalid query string before transfering the request.

Comment: Do you really need to redirect to the error page in the first place? A potential solution would be to create a global filter to catch when an error occurs and populate the ViewBag with the content you want to display in the alert box (without navigating to an error page). Sure, you would miss any errors that occur before ASP.NET executes, but how important are those for your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [HttpContext.RewritePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath?view=netframework-4.8) instead. Use an empty queryString (`""`) to prevent it from using the query string of the current request.